# unique_ptr calls method after using std::move

Tags: c++

**Code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Test {
public:
    void TestFunc() {
        std::cout << "TestFunc()\n";
    }
};

int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<Test> ptr1(new Test);
    ptr1->TestFunc();

    std::unique_ptr<Test> ptr2 = std::move(ptr1);
    ptr2->TestFunc();

    if (ptr1 == nullptr) {
        std::cout << "Now ptr1 is nullptr\n";
    }

    ptr1->TestFunc(); // !!
}
```

**Result:**

```
TestFunc()
TestFunc()
Now ptr1 is nullptr
TestFunc() // !!
```

Like above code, the ownership of `Test` object is moved from `ptr1` to `ptr2`.

However, still I can call `TestFunc()` through `ptr1` even though `ptr1` has confirmed as `nullptr` after moving. How is this possible?

Comment: @NathanOliver thanks for adding it as a duplicate

Comment: Your function is not virtual, does not access this pointer, so the compiler just generate the call with a this pointer to null ... that's all.

Comment: Dereferencing a `nullptr` is undefined behavior. So basically, everything can happen. Maybe your compiler spilled the same address for the pointer stored in `ptr1` assuming "something". Noone can actually exactly tell, because it is undefined.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This code works same in gcc and msvc so I thought it is a standard behavior.

Comment: What @Gojita said: https://ideone.com/43YeUx (even tho, yes, it is UB).